# Topology question regarding vehicle

Tags: topology

I am struggling with modeling the roof and keeping it in clean topology. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the roundness and smoothness of the roof to match the real reference. How should I go about it?

[image]

[This](http://ccmv.aecsouthall.co.uk/p548596651/h3f1b797#h5a13fb80) is what I am trying to mimic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using Bevel on all of your corners?

Another method would be Extrude, Spin and Tweek. Lots of tweeking needed  :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please separate the text so that is not part of the image. That way the text would be searchable, and editable.